# PCRE to replace #334455 hex with #345

Tags: php, regex, hex, preg-replace, pcre

I'm writing a function that replaces long hex coded color (`#334455`) with short one (`#345`). This can be only done when each color in hex is multiple of 17 (each hex pair consists of the same characters).

e.g. `#EEFFCC` is replaced with `#EFC`, but #`EDFFCC` isn't replaced with anything.

I want to make this with single `preg_replace()` call without any custom callbacks.

I've already tried this:

```
$hex = preg_replace('/([0-f]){2}([0-f]){2}([0-f]){2}/i', '\1\2\3', $hex);
```

But that shortens all hexes, not just the hexes with same characters in each pair. I can't figure out how to match only pairs of same character.

Please help.

Comment: [0-9a-f] would probably work better than [0-f].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - you just need to use the [backreferences](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) in the match itself

```
$hex = preg_replace('/([0-f])\1([0-f])\2([0-f])\3/i', '\1\2\3', $hex);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, I didn't know that backreferences can be used in patterns too. That brings a whole new dimension to regexps. :)